# CSV Reading as empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I've got a page where by intervals of around 10 minutes a csv file is uploaded to a folder (received by an http link). This csv file has to be uploaded to sql. I've managed to get the csv files and save them in the folder, but the problem that I've got is that when I try and read the data it shows that the file is empty (but it is not)... It doesn't throw any errors, but when I run it with a debug, it shows an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

This is my code...

Method of what has to happen for this entire process:

```
    private void RunCSVGetToSqlOrder()
    {
        DAL d = new DAL();

        GetGeoLocations();

        string geoLocPath = Server.MapPath("~\\GeoLocations\\GeoLocation.csv");
        string assetListPath = Server.MapPath("~\\GeoLocations\\AssetList.csv");

        d.InsertAssetGeoLocation(ImportGeoLocations(geoLocPath));
        d.InsertAssetList(ImportAssetList(assetListPath));

        DeleteFileFromFolder();
    }
```

Getting the csv and saving into a folder (working):

```
    private void GetGeoLocations()
    {
        string linkGeoLoc = "http://app03.gpsts.co.za/io/api/asset_group/APIAssetGroupLocation.class?zqcEK60SxfoP4fVppcLoCXFWUfVRVkKS@auth_token@auth_token";
        string filepathGeoLoc = Server.MapPath("~\\GeoLocations\\GeoLocation.csv");

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(linkGeoLoc), filepathGeoLoc);
        }
    }
```

Read csv file and import to sql:

```
    private static DataTable ImportGeoLocations(string csvFilePath)
    {
        DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csvFilePath))
            {
              //  csvReader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                csvReader.TrimWhiteSpace = true;

                string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();

                foreach (string column in colFields)
                {
                    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                    csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                }
                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    //Making empty value as null
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fieldData[i] == "")
                        {
                            fieldData[i] = null;
                        }
                    }
                    csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return csvData;
    }
```

The above code gives the error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the line, but this is most probably due because it's reading the csv as empty(null)...

```
    string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... Any advice would be greatly appreciated...

------------ EDIT --------------

The csv file after the download looks as follows:

[image]

-------- Solution ------------

Below is the solution:

```
     private void RunCSVGetToSqlOrder()
    {
        GetGeoLocations();
        DeleteFileFromFolder();
    }

    private void GetGeoLocations()
    {
        string linkGeoLoc = "http://app03.gpsts.co.za/io/api/asset_group/APIAssetGroupLocation.class?zqcEK60SxfoP4fVppcLoCXFWUfVRVkKS@auth_token@auth_token";
        string filepathGeoLoc = Server.MapPath("~\\GeoLocations\\GeoLocation.csv");

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(linkGeoLoc), filepathGeoLoc);
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompletedGeoLoc);
        }

        string linkAssetList = "http://app03.gpsts.co.za/io/api/asset_group/APIAssetGroupLocation.class?zqcEK60SxfoP4fVppcLoCXFWUfVRVkKS@auth_token@auth_token";
        string filepathAssetList = Server.MapPath("~\\GeoLocations\\AssetList.csv");

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(linkAssetList), filepathAssetList);
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompletedAssetList);
        }
    }

    void wc_DownloadFileCompletedGeoLoc(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DAL d = new DAL();

        string geoLocPath = Server.MapPath("~\\GeoLocations\\GeoLocation.csv");
        d.InsertAssetGeoLocation(ImportGeoLocations(geoLocPath));
    }

    void wc_DownloadFileCompletedAssetList(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DAL d = new DAL();

        string assetListPath = Server.MapPath("~\\GeoLocations\\AssetList.csv");
        d.InsertAssetList(ImportAssetList(assetListPath));
    }
```

Comment: This is evil: `catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }`

Comment: I haven't done the code exception/catch as yet... will do that part as soon as I can get this working....

Comment: But don't start coding with empty catch blocks. It makes it much harder to find bugs. You could at least set a breakpoint there to see the comple message and stacktrace inlcuding line number.

Comment: Thanks I will do this part right now then, thanks for the advice

Comment: ... for example if your `csvReader` is not initialised properly, because it threw an error that you're not aware of because of your evil catch block, that would explain your error - nothing to do with the file being empty.

Comment: You say that `GetGeoLocations` is working. Are you absolutely sure that it is completely working? I would expect some kind of await mechanism for the `wc.DownloadFileAsync` call in order to assure complete download instead of only creating an empty file where the download content will be placed.

Comment: yes, I am completely sure... After the dowload I can open the csv file and see all the data...

Comment: I have updated my question showing the data that is being saved (this is from the csv after the download)....

Comment: I know I may be persistent on an unrelated matter (or not) but did you really triple-check the timing? Since `wc.DownloadFileAsync` returns a `Task` object and you don't handle it, there is a high possibility of the task completing whenever you reach a breakpoint, so you will never actually inspect the empty file situation of the still running task. However, the code execution without any waiting mechanism is likely to reach `d.InsertAssetGeoLocation(ImportGeoLocations(geoLocPath))` before the download task completes.

Comment: @Grek40, Thanks, I added a DownloadFileComplete handler, and seems like this was the problem. It was reaching the sql insert before the time, it is working great now. Thanks, will you please add this as an answer so that I can close the thread please? Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `wc.DownloadFileAsync` returns a `Task` object and the downloaded file is only complete after the Task is completed.

This issue is hard to catch with the debugger, because the task will have enough time to complete when a breakpoint is reached or the file is manually inspected later. However, when the code runs without break point, the call `d.InsertAssetGeoLocation(ImportGeoLocations(geoLocPath))` will be reached before the download is complete and therefore the csv file will be empty.

Possible solutions:

- Redesign the code with `async` / `await`
- Use `wd.DownloadFileCompleted` event for continuation
- Use the synchronous `wd.DownloadFile` method

... just to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, it looks like the CSV file is not read properly on your computer. Depending on the language and region settings, the .CSV sometimes has ";" as seperators instead of ",".

Could you try manually replacing all "," with ";" and see if it solves the issue?

Comment: Thanks, changing the character works, it is reading the file then, but how do I change this on code side and not manually? sorry this is my fist time working with this... The file will be replaced every 10minutes for the latest locations of the vihicles, thus I can't manually change it every time... Thanks